# TensorFlow: tf.case() & f_default should do nothing

Tags: tensorflow

I'm working on a network with 4 class-specific autoencoders (3 layer feedforward), and within the training iteration, there is a case check to decide, which autoencoder has to be updated:

```
def f(k): return tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lernrate).minimize(Cost_List[k]), n_List[k].assign_add(1.0), Cost_List[k]

def g(): ???

nothing = g()



min_index = tf.argmin(Cost_List, 0) 

Case_0 = (tf.equal(min_index,0), lambda: f(0))
Case_1 = (tf.equal(min_index,1), lambda: f(1))
Case_2 = (tf.equal(min_index,2), lambda: f(2))
Case_3 = (tf.equal(min_index,3), lambda: f(3))


Case_List = [Case_0, Case_1, Case_2, Case_3]

[optimizer, update, cost] = tf.case(Case_List, nothing)
```

In the case, that no condition is fulfilled, nothing should be done. In this scenario, one of the four cases will be realized, so it's no practical problem here yet, but I want to modify the code, and then it will be important, that the training sample will be skipped in the default case. The problem is, that the return type(s) of f_default and all other return types have to be the same, because sess.run([optimizer, update, cost]) is expecting a certain type. How can I do this, that really nothing happens in the default case? I have already tried to use tf.no_op() but that's not working...

Thanks,

Meridius

Answer (score 1):

To make the signatures match, you could define `g()` as follows:

```
def g():
  return tf.no_op(), tf.no_op(), tf.constant(0.0)
```

Note that it would be slightly more efficient to pass `g` directly as `f_default` (as opposed to passing `g()` as the current code does) but the behaviour should be the same.